# GoogleCloudMessaging PHP script always returning NotRegistered

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know there are lots of posts with the same issue, but after read all of them I could not find the reason of the problem.

I wrote a GCM client to register my device to receive messages from my server. It is working and I can store the registration ID in my database.

My problem is in the server side. I'm using a script found somewhere googling, but I always receive an error result:

```
{"multicast_id":5185959414153599391,"success":0,"failure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

The PHP code is (I'm using BROWSER API instead of SERVER API as told on tutorial, but trying both keys returns the same message):

```
$this->db->SELECT('device_id');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('status = 1');
$this->db->where("id IN (".$param['first_friend'].",".$param['second_friend'].")");
$query_id = $this->db->get();
$result_id = $query_id->result_array();
$gcmRegIds = array(trim($result_id[0]['device_id']), trim($result_id[1]['device_id']));

if ($result[0]['username']) {
       $name = $result[0]['username'];
} else {
       $name = $result[0]['name'];
}

$pushMessage = $name." was created meeting to you.";

if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {
        $message = array('message' => $pushMessage);
        $pushStatus = $this->send_notification($gcmRegIds, $message);
}
```

And my function is,

```
function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I put the real ids and key to see if I'm doing right. Any ideas?

Comment: basically it comes either your project id or device id is wrong, please recheck it

Comment: @bornprogrammer, you mean project id is API KEY?

Comment: there is two thing out here
1) one is project id which would be used from android end when you need to register the device id

2) you need api key when you will send the push the message to gcm server

Comment: Yes i have added api key and send a two same device id. i expect two notification from the cgm, but i got only NotRegistered message

Comment: please make sure couple of thing
1) your project id is correct which you are using to register gcm server
2) try to use another device if available otherwise unregister the register device and try again

Comment: please put your concern here... will try my best to respond asap :)